# Delete and update Google events [Google Calendar] using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-calendar-api

How I can add in my website the update and delete events to my Google Calendar using ASP.NET C#?

Comment: You're looking for the Google Calendar API.

Comment: no , i am searching how to manipulate my events (delete,update) from my website

Comment: Please take a look here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet

Comment: You're still looking for the Google Calendar API

Answer (score 2):

You can use the methods [Calendars: update](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/update) to update metadata for a calendar. and [Calendars: delete](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/delete) to delete a secondary calendar. Use [Calendars.clear](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/clear) for clearing all events on primary calendars.

Sample HTTP requests:

Update: `PUT https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId`
Delete: `DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId`
Clear: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/clear`

Found this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-calendar-api/gZO18rvvqHM) with a working .NET code for Google Calendar API V3.

Update Event:

```
 public string CreateUpdateEvent(string ExpKey, string ExpVal, string evTitle, string evDate)
    {
        EventsResource er = new EventsResource(calService);
        var queryEvent = er.List(calID);
        queryEvent.SharedExtendedProperty = ExpKey + "=" + ExpVal; //"EventKey=9999"
        var EventsList = queryEvent.Execute();

        Event ev = new Event();
        EventDateTime StartDate = new EventDateTime();
        StartDate.Date = evDate; //"2014-11-17";
        EventDateTime EndDate = new EventDateTime();
        EndDate.Date = evDate;

        ev.Start = StartDate;
        ev.End = EndDate;
        ev.Summary = evTitle; //"My Google Calendar V3 Event!";

        string FoundEventID = String.Empty;
        foreach(var evItem in EventsList.Items)
        {
            FoundEventID = evItem.Id;
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(FoundEventID))
        {
            //If event does not exist, Append Extended Property and create the event
            Event.ExtendedPropertiesData exp = new Event.ExtendedPropertiesData();
            exp.Shared = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            exp.Shared.Add(ExpKey, ExpVal);
            ev.ExtendedProperties = exp;
            return er.Insert(ev, calID).Execute().Summary;
        }
        else
        {
            //If existing, Update the event
            return er.Update(ev, calID, FoundEventID).Execute().Summary;
        }
    }
```

Delete Event:

```
public bool DeleteEvent(string ExpKey, string ExpVal)
    {
        EventsResource er = new EventsResource(calService);
        var queryEvent = er.List(calID);

        queryEvent.SharedExtendedProperty = ExpKey + "=" + ExpVal; //"EventKey=9999"
        var EventsList = queryEvent.Execute();

        string FoundEventID = String.Empty;
        foreach (Event ev in EventsList.Items)
        {
            FoundEventID = ev.Id;
            er.Delete(calID, FoundEventID).Execute();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Check also this [Quickstart tutorial from Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet).